# Laminas\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laminas

I have set up a basic application with the Laminas MVC Skeleton Application.

I have created a module Test with the following structure:

```
Test
|- config
|  |- module.config.php
|- src
|  |- Controller
|  |  |- IndexController.php
|  |- Form
|  |- Model
|  |- Module.php
|- view
   |- test
   |  |- index
   |  |  |- index.phtml
```

IndexController.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\Controller;

use Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
    }
}
```

view_manager configuration:

```
'view_manager' => [
    'template_path_stack' => [
        __DIR__ . '../view',
    ],
],
```

But I get the following error

```
Laminas\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "test/index/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file
```

I expect it to search for the index.phtml template in /view/test/index but it can not find it.

How to fix this?

Comment: Actually, correct would be `'template_path_stack' => [__DIR__ . '/../view', ],`. E.g. notice the first _slash ("/")_ character after `__DIR__`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the subfolder "view/test/index" in "view/test/test"

```
|- view
   |- test
   |  |- test
   |  |  |- index.phtml
```

And then change the configuration in this way:

```
'view_manager' => [
    'template_path_stack' => [
         'test' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ],
],
```